# Inserting data when using BelongsTo mapping in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to implement `belongsTo` mapping in my Laravel 4 application. But I can't seem to get it working.

I have a db table named : **questions:**

```
question_id | question_title | question_details| ask_by_id | created_at|  updated_at
```

**Here `ask_by_id` is the foreign key of `users` table**

The problem I am facing is when I insert data into the table all the column values get inserted properly except the `ask_by_id` column. If I am not wrong since I am using `belongTo` mapping, Laravel is supposed to automatically insert the current user's `id` value in the `ask_by_id` column for me. But its not happening, could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here are my codes:

Model : Question

```
class Question extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = "questions";
 protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';
 protected $fillable = array('question_title','question_details','ask_by_id');

 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'ask_by_id', 'id');
 }
}
```

In User Model, I have included the following code:

```
public function question()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Question');
}
```

In my Controller, I am using the following code to insert form data.

```
 $question = new Question();
 $question->question_title = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->question_details = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->user();
 $question->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use it wrong. Using `user()` means nothing in this case. You should also alter your relation for `User`:

```
public function question()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Question','ask_by_id', 'id');
}
```

When using:

```
 $question = new Question();
 $question->question_title = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->question_details = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->user();
 $question->save();
```

Laravel doesn't know what to insert into `ask_by_id`.

You could use the following code:

```
 $user = User::find($id); // or $user = Auth::user();
 $question = new Question();
 $question->question_title = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->question_details = Input::get('question_title');
 $user->question()->save($question);
```

or

```
 $question = new Question();
 $question->question_title = Input::get('question_title');
 $question->question_details = Input::get('question_title');

 $user = User::find($id); // or $user = Auth::user();
 $question->ask_by_id = $user->id;
 $question->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use your first solution, I get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'` Thanks

Comment: @black_belt You should also alter your relation. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be inserted automatically you have to do this explicity there are few ways to do this.

One of them is to fill the ask_by_id like this.

```
$question->ask_by_id = $userId;
$question->save();
```

The other can be

First update your question method to

```
public function question()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Question','ask_by_id');
}
```

Then find the user who has asked the questions

```
     $user = User::find(1);
     $question = new Question();
     $question->question_title = Input::get('question_title');
     $question->question_details = Input::get('question_title');
     $user->question()->save($question);
```

This will update the ask_by_id automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried the other solution I got this error `Call to undefined method  Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()` , thanks